# AWK filescript printing after a 2D array print

Tags: linux, awk

I've been trying print after a 2D printf but the print that I put after the array happens before the 2D array print.

this is the code in question (its in an awk script):

`(in main block)
    if(tot >= 500) {
    totEligible++
    eligibles[totEligible,1] = $1
    eligibles[totEligible,2] = $2
    }
      (in end block)
     {
   # print out all the eligible contributors' information
    for(i = 1; i <= totEligible; i++) {
   printf("\t%s--%s\n", eligibles[i,1], eligibles[i,2]) | "sort -k2"
   if (i == totEligible -1){
   printf "\t\tThanks for all your continued support!!!"
    }
  }
}`

The output is showing this:

 `Thanks for all your continued support!!!        John Goldenrod--(916) 348-4278
        Mike Harrington--(510) 548-1278
        Archie McNichol--(206) 548-1348
        Guy Quigley--(916) 343-6410
        Dan Savage--(406) 298-7744
        Tom Savage--(408) 926-3456
        Elizabeth Stachelin--(916) 440-1763`

It should be showing below the Elizabeth Stachelin line but it isn't doing that. Any idea what the problem might be? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code will speak for itself. make your Q so people can copy/paste code and data. Also indicate your required output VS your current output with any comment you have on why you think it is not working or where you need help Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box on selected text to keep it as code/data/errMsgs/output. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the shell pipe with `close("sort -k2")` before your thank-you print. Look:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "b" ORS "a" | "sort"; print "Done!"}'
Done!
a
b

$ awk 'BEGIN{print "b" ORS "a" | "sort"; close("sort"); print "Done!"}'
a
b
Done!
```

In your script the "sort" is just sitting around waiting for more input until the script ends (after your thank you print has occurred) and THEN closing the pipe to sort and outputting the result of that sort.

It's best practice to store the shell command in a variable so you can guarantee to execute `close()` on the exact same string you are piping to:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{cmd="sort"; print "b" ORS "a" | cmd; close(cmd); print "Done!"}'
a
b
Done!
```

otherwise you could be trying to close a pipe that doesn't exist and awk will cheerfully do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

put your thanks print after the close of your for loop
(without any if i == totEligible -1 )